# ZF: nginx to serve images/css/js/files and apache to serve .php

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, nginx

Hi i need to configure my webserver that runs a Zend Framework based Application:

My idea is to use: 
nginx to serve images, files (zip/doc/xls/...), js ,html, ...
apache to serve the requests to zf actions

how can i setup it ?

thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your Apache is running on port 8080 and your Nginx is running on port 80.

Your static files are located at /var/www/static/ and the folder structure there fully reflect HTTP requests expected.

Then (with some your context specific changes) it might be something like:

```
upstream zend {
    server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  frontend;

    location / {
        alias /var/www/static/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @zend;
    }

    location @zend {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://zend;
    }
}
```